# Razor pay in flutter first time always the app crashes

Tags: android, flutter, razorpay, razorpay-andoid-sdk

E/ActivityThread: Activity com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.razorpay.b__J_@837b24 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.razorpay.CheckoutActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.razorpay.b__J_@837b24 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

I tried to update the razorpay plugin from native android to 1.6.26.
Updated proguard file as well..
Still it crashes in android alone, ios is fine.

Comment: Had you used any type of receiver in your app ? Error says it clearly that when you register receiver , in that file onDestroy or onStop  must contain unregister receiver..

Comment: i have integrated razorpay flutter, and i have cleared it in the onDispose() method,,,